# Conversion from ES6 to ES5 throwing Syntax error

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am trying to convert a directive from ES6 to ES5. It is giving me syntactical errors at scope stating "Expecting newline or semicolon" and also at link : function stating "Function statement should be at top level of program". Can someone help change this ES6 directive to ES5

Directive in ES6

```
directives.directive('clickAndWait', () => ({
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            asyncAction: '&clickAndWait',
        },
        link: (scope, element) => {
        element.bind('click', () => {

        element.prop('disabled', true);
    // element.addClass('state-waiting');
    scope.$apply(() => {
        scope.asyncAction().finally(() => {
        element.prop('disabled', false);
    // element.removeClass('state-waiting');
});
});
});
},
}));
```

My code in ES5

```
        directives.directive('clickAndWait', function () {
       return {
           restrict : 'A',
           scope : {
               asyncAction: '&clickAndWait'
           },
           link : function(scope, element, attr) {
               element.bind('click', function(){
                   element.prop('disabled', true);
                   scope.$apply(function () {
                       scope.asyncAction().finally(function () {
                           element.prop('disabled', false);
                       })
                   })
               });
           }
       }

    });
```

Comment: `function () { foo: bar, baz: abc, ...}` doesn't make much sense. If you want to create an object then you have to do `function() { return {foo: ..., bar:, ... };`. You can learn more about objects on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Comment: I am just trying to convert as it is from es6 to es5. can you show me the correct way in es5 converting the directive?

Comment: I did, but here it is again: `() => ({})` becomes `function() { return {}; }`. The arrow function returns an object, hence your function expression also has to return an object. Please don't take this the wrong way, but do you not know what the meaning of `() => ({})` is?

Comment: I am sorry If I am asking amateur questions. But I don't know how that works. I have never seen any ES6 syntax before

Comment: This might help then: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions .

Comment: I got the point of returning the object. I have made changes in my code accordingly.  Should I return the object  for element.bind() and scope.$apply also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly renaming `() => {` to `function () {`. But also making sure to add the return statement to the directive function, which is implicit in arrow functions.

```
directives.directive('clickAndWait', function() {
    var directiveConfig = {

        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            asyncAction: '&clickAndWait',
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.bind('click', function() {

                element.prop('disabled', true);
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.asyncAction().finally(function() {
                        element.prop('disabled', false);
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    };

    return directiveConfig;
});
```